# How to get percentage using "onUploadProgress" axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm currently struggling in getting the percentage from the `onUploadProgress` of **axios**. The code below does printing the right percentage.

My problem is how to make the `percentage` value accessible in **List.js** file?

**UsersApi.js**

```
importUsersList: (payload) => {
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/users/import ',
      data: payload,
      onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
        const { loaded, total } = progressEvent;
        let percentage = Math.floor((loaded * 100) / total);
        console.log('percentage => ', percentage);
      },
    };

    return API.request(options);
};
```

**List.js**

```
dispatch(importUsersList(file));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to display the upload progress in the `List` component.

That means you need to introduce e.g. an `uploadedPercent: number` field into `List`'s state.

Since it looks like you're using some sort of reducer, you need to dispatch an action – for example `setUploadProgress(uploadedPercent: number)`, which will change your state.

That action needs to be dispatched in `onUploadProgress`.

You can then change the signature to `importUsersList(payload, onUploadProgress)` and pass the handler:

```js
const onUploadProgress = (progressEvent) => {
  const { loaded, total } = progressEvent;
  const percentage = Math.floor((loaded * 100) / total);
  dispatch(setUploadProgress(percentage));
};

dispatch(importUsersList(file, onUploadProgress));
```